# mostrar y ocultar div cuando se seleccione algun checkbox

Tags: javascript

saben como puedo hacer para que cuando seleccione el checkbox cambie de estilo un div con texto a "display:block;"? cada checkbox es independiente, por ende, si selecciono el 1 checkbox se deberia mostrar "textoSeleccionado1" y si selecciono el checkbox 2 se deberia mostrara el "textoSeleccionado2" mas el "textoSeleccionado1" que ya esta seleccionado previamente y así con todos. tengo mi codigo con js que me funciona en otro proyecto pero aca no me sirve.
gracias de antemano.

```js
function showContent() {
  check1 = document.getElementById("1");
  if (check1.checked) {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado1").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado1").style.display = "none";
  }
  check2 = document.getElementById("2");
  if (check2.checked) {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado2").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado2").style.display = "none";
  }
  check3 = document.getElementById("3");
  if (check3.checked) {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado3").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado3").style.display = "none";
  }
  check4 = document.getElementById("4");
  if (check4.checked) {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado4").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado4").style.display = "none";
  }
  check5 = document.getElementById("5");
  if (check5.checked) {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado5").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado5").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.textoSeleccionado1,
.textoSeleccionado2,
.textoSeleccionado3,
.textoSeleccionado4,
.textoSeleccionado5,
.textoSeleccionado6,
.textoSeleccionado7,
.textoSeleccionado8,
.textoSeleccionado9,
.textoSeleccionado10,
.textoSeleccionado12,
.textoSeleccionado13,
.textoSeleccionado14,
.textoSeleccionado15,
.textoSeleccionado16,
.textoSeleccionado17,
.textoSeleccionado18 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="2">
            <label for="2">Ayuda a controlar el peso</label>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="3">
            <label for="3"> Mejora el estado de ánimo</label>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="4">
            <label for="4">Disminuye el estrés</label>
          </div>
          <div class="seleccion">
            <input type="checkbox" id="5">
            <label for="5">Aumenta la productividad</label>
          </div>
          </div>
          <a class="styleBtn" onclick="showContent()" href="#">Continuar</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo el cambio que hice

1. los estilos los coloque como #textoSeleccionado1, #textoSeleccionado2...
2. Agregue el checkbox con id=1 que no lo tenias
3. agregue los div que se muestran al presionar continuar según el checkbox seleccionado  Texto #1

Codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textoSeleccionado1,
#textoSeleccionado2,
#textoSeleccionado3,
#textoSeleccionado4,
#textoSeleccionado5,
#textoSeleccionado6,
#textoSeleccionado7,
#textoSeleccionado8,
#textoSeleccionado9,
#textoSeleccionado10,
#textoSeleccionado12,
#textoSeleccionado13,
#textoSeleccionado14,
#textoSeleccionado15,
#textoSeleccionado16,
#textoSeleccionado17,
#textoSeleccionado18 {
display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="seleccion">
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<label for="1">Nuevo Checkbox</label>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
<input type="checkbox" id="2">
<label for="2">Ayuda a controlar el peso</label>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
<input type="checkbox" id="3">
<label for="3"> Mejora el estado de ánimo</label>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
<input type="checkbox" id="4">
<label for="4">Disminuye el estrés</label>
</div>
<div class="seleccion">
<input type="checkbox" id="5">
<label for="5">Aumenta la productividad</label>
</div>

<div id="textoSeleccionado1">Texto #1</div>
<div id="textoSeleccionado2">Texto #2</div>
<div id="textoSeleccionado3">Texto #3</div>
<div id="textoSeleccionado4">Texto #4</div>
<div id="textoSeleccionado5">Texto #5</div>

<a class="styleBtn" onclick="showContent()" href="#">Continuar</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showContent() {

check1 = document.getElementById("1");
if (check1.checked) {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado1").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado1").style.display = "none";
}

check2 = document.getElementById("2");
if (check2.checked) {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado2").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado2").style.display = "none";
}
check3 = document.getElementById("3");
if (check3.checked) {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado3").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado3").style.display = "none";
}
check4 = document.getElementById("4");
if (check4.checked) {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado4").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado4").style.display = "none";
}
check5 = document.getElementById("5");
if (check5.checked) {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado5").style.display = "block";
} else {
document.getElementById("textoSeleccionado5").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Primero** de todo, errores:

Declara las variables como tales, cambia esto:

```
function showContent() {
    check1 = document.getElementById("1");
    // ...
}
```

por esto otro:

```
function showContent() {
    const check1 = document.getElementById("1");
    // ...
}
```

Luego, no puedes usar un número como identificador de un elemento HTML. Cambia:

```
const check1 = document.getElementById("1");
```

por (algo como):

```
const check1 = document.getElementById("check1");
```

**Segundo**, estas haciendo muchas cosas una y otra vez, por ejemplo, al seleccionar / deseleccionar un *checkbox*:

- Seleccionar un elemento por su ID y añadirle un `display none`
- Seleccionar un elemento por su ID y añadirle un `display block`

Es más limpio y sencillo si usas funciones para esto, p.e.:

```
function setDisplayNone(elementId) // void
{
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "none";
}

function setDisplayBlock(elementId) // void
{
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
}
```

Los bloques quedarán así:

```
  const check1 = document.getElementById("1");
  if (check1.checked) {
    setDisplayBlock("textoSeleccionado1");
  } else {
    setDisplayNone("textoSeleccionado1");
  }
```

**Tercero**, agrupa las declaraciones por tipo / uso:

```
function showContent()
{
    const check1 = document.getElementById("1");
    const check2 = document.getElementById("2");
    const check3 = document.getElementById("3");
    const check4 = document.getElementById("4");
    const check5 = document.getElementById("5");

    if (check1.checked) {
        setDisplayBlock("textoSeleccionado1");
    } else {
        setDisplayNone("textoSeleccionado1");
    }

    if (check2.checked) {
        setDisplayBlock("textoSeleccionado2");
    } else {
        setDisplayNone("textoSeleccionado2");
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Cuarto**, refactoriza. Sigue habiendo demasiadas acciones repetitivas.

**Quinto y último**, necesitas asignar un escuchador de evento a cada uno de los checkboxes para saber cuando se seleccionan o deseleccionan, de otro modo el script solo se ejecuta cuando se carga la página y veras los textos según el estado que les asignes a los checkboxes en tu HTML inicialmente.

El ***código final*** podría ser algo así:

```
function getNodeById(elementId) // js node
{
    return document.getElementById(elementId);
}
function setDisplayBlock(elementId) // void
{
    getNodeById(elementId).style.display = "block";
}
function setDisplayNone(elementId) // void
{
    getNodeById(elementId).style.display = "none";
}

function showContent(totalCheckboxes = 5) // void
{
    for (let index = 1; index <= totalCheckboxes; index++) {

        const checkboxId = 'check' + index;
        const textId = 'textoSeleccionado' + index;

        const checkboxNode = getNodeById(checkboxId);
        checkboxNode.addEventListener('click', function() // void
        {
            if (checkboxNode.checked) {
                setDisplayBlock(textId);
            } else {
                setDisplayNone(textId);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Donde la función `showContent` recibe como parámetro el número de checkboxes / textos que se van a utilizar.*

> Editado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <label for="check_1">Show 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_1" id="check_1">
            <p id="text_1" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="check_2">Show 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_2" id="check_2">
            <p id="text_2" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="check_3">Show 3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="check_3" id="check_3">
            <p id="text_3" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum 3</p>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script>
        function qs(selector) // js node
        {
            return document.querySelector(selector);
        }
        function qsa(selector) // js node
        {
            return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }
        function setDisplayBlock(elementId) // void
        {
            qs('#' + elementId).style.display = 'block';
        }
        function setDisplayNone(elementId) // void
        {
            qs('#' + elementId).style.display = 'none';
        }

        function showContent(totalCheckboxes = 5) // void
        {
            for (let index = 1; index <= totalCheckboxes; index++) {

                const checkboxId = 'check_' + index;
                const textId = 'text_' + index;

                const checkboxNode = qs('#' + checkboxId);
                checkboxNode.addEventListener('click', function () // void
                {
                    if (checkboxNode.checked) {
                        setDisplayBlock(textId);
                    } else {
                        setDisplayNone(textId);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const checkboxesTotal = qsa('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        showContent(checkboxesTotal);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excelente, refactorizando.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo dos opciones, la primera muestra o no muestra los divs dependiendo de si está o no en checked el checkbox. La segunda chequea todos los checkbox de la página y al presionar continuar, solo muestra los divs correspondientes.

Opción 1 HTML:

```
<body> 
    <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" onchange="showContent(this.id)">
        <label for="2">Ayuda a controlar el peso</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto1">Texto Seleccionado 1</div>
      
      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="showContent(this.id)" id="2">
        <label for="3"> Mejora el estado de ánimo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto2">Texto Seleccionado 2</div>

      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="showContent(this.id)" id="3">
        <label for="4">Disminuye el estrés</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto3">Texto Seleccionado 3</div>

      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" onchange="showContent(this.id)" id="4">
        <label for="5">Aumenta la productividad</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto4">Texto Seleccionado 4</div>
      </div>
      <a class="styleBtn" onclick="showContent()" href="#">Continuar</a>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Opción 1 JavaScript

```
function showContent(id) {
  const selectedCheckbox = document.getElementById(id);
  const divToShow = document.getElementById("Texto" + id);
  selectedCheckbox.checked
    ? (divToShow.style.display = "block")
    : (divToShow.style.display = "none");
}
```

---

Opción 2 HTML:

```
<body> 
    <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1" 
        <label for="2">Ayuda a controlar el peso</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto1">Texto Seleccionado 1</div>
      
      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2">
        <label for="3"> Mejora el estado de ánimo</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto2">Texto Seleccionado 2</div>

      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="3">
        <label for="4">Disminuye el estrés</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto3">Texto Seleccionado 3</div>

      <div class="seleccion">
        <input type="checkbox" id="4">
        <label for="5">Aumenta la productividad</label>
      </div>
      <div class="initialHide" id="Texto4">Texto Seleccionado 4</div>
      </div>
      <a class="styleBtn" onclick="showContent()" href="#">Continuar</a>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Opción 2 JavaScript:

```
function showContent() {
  const allCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"');
  for (const checkBox of allCheckBox) {
    const selectedCheckbox = document.getElementById(checkBox.id);
    const divToShow = document.getElementById("Texto" + checkBox.id);
    selectedCheckbox.checked
      ? (divToShow.style.display = "block")
      : (divToShow.style.display = "none");
  }
}
```

En ambos agregue a los divs una clase "initialHide" que la utilizo para que inicialmente no se muestre ninguno.

Entonces en CSS agregué algo así:

```
.initialHide {
    display: none;
}
```

Con esto debería ser suficiente.

Breve explicación:

En el primer caso cada que cambia el estado de un checkbox llama a la función pasandole como argumento el id del checkbox, luego concateno la palabra Texto+ID del checkbox y así capturo el Div correspondiente, una vez hecho eso verifico, si está chequeado lo muestro, sino lo oculto.

En el segundo caso recorro todos los checkbox, podrías agregar cuantos desees, y por cada checkbox repito el procedimiento del primer ejemplo, solo que esta vez en vez llamar a la función con el id como argumento, ahora se llama a la función solo cuando se presiona continuar y recorre automáticamente todos los checkboxes.

Por último y por las dudas, lo siguiente se llama operador ternario.

```
 selectedCheckbox.checked
    ? (divToShow.style.display = "block")
    : (divToShow.style.display = "none");
```

Es lo mismo en este caso que:

```
if(selectedCheckbox.checked){
    (divToShow.style.display = "block")
} else {
     (divToShow.style.display = "none")
}
```

Espero sirva para lo que necesitas hacer, quedo a las órdenes.